# Crazy C++ template - A template to access individual attributes of a class

Tags: c++, templates, pointer-to-member

I am a novice C++ programmer, but I thought I know enough about C++ until today when I came across code like this at work and failed to understand how it actually works.

```
class Object
{
};

template <
        class PropObject,
        class PropType, 
        PropType PropObject::* Prop
        >
class PropReader
{
public:
    void print(Object& o)
    {
        PropObject& po = static_cast<PropObject &>(o);
        PropType& t = po.*Prop;

        cout << t << "\n";
    }
};

class Student : public Object
{
public:
    int age;
    int grade;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{   
    Student s;
    s.age = 10;
    s.grade = 5;

    PropReader<Student, int, &Student::age> r;
    PropReader<Student, int, &Student::grade> r2;

    r.print(s);
    r2.print(s);
}
```

I think I kind of understood at a high level. But this particular `PropType PropObject::* Prop` in the template declaration bothers me. What does it mean? I am looking for an explanation from C++ experts. I would like to understand it, so that I can use it better. It looks very useful though.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

C++ templates are well-known for taking types as arguments, but they can also be parameterized over other types of data as well.  For example, you could templatize a class over an integer, as shown here:

```
template <typename T, unsigned int N> class Array {
private:
    T array[N];

public:
    /* ... */
};
```

Templates can also be parameterized over pointers, as long as the pointer meets certain criteria (for example, it has to evaluate to an address of something that can be determined at compile-time).  For example, this is perfectly legal:

```
template <int* Pointer> class ThisIsLegal {
public:
    void doSomething() {
        *Pointer = 137;
    }
};
```

In your code, the template is parameterized over a *pointer-to-class-member*.  A pointer-to-class-member is similar to a pointer in that it indirectly refers to some object.  However, instead of pointing to an object, instead it points to a field in a class.  The idea is that you can dereference a pointer-to-class-member relative to some object to select that field out of the class.  Here's a simple example of pointers-to-class-member:

```
struct MyStruct {
    int x, y;
};

int main() {
    MyStruct ms;
    ms.x = 137;
    ms.y = 42;

    int MyStruct::* ptr; // Declare a pointer to a class member.
    ptr = &MyStruct::x;  // Now points to the field 'x'

    ms.*ptr = 0;         // Set the 'x' field of ms to be zero.
}
```

Notice that the syntax for declaring a pointer-to-class-member is

```
Type ContainingClass::* pointerName;
```

So in the above code, `int MyStruct::* ptr` means "a pointer to an `int` inside of a `MyStruct` class.

In the code that you've posted, the template declaration reads like this:

```
template <
    class PropObject,
    class PropType, 
    PropType PropObject::* Prop
    >
class PropReader
```

Let's see what this means.  The first two template argument object whose property is going to be read, and `PropType`, the type of that property."  The final argument to the template is a pointer-to-class-member named `Prop` that points inside a `PropObject` at a field of type `PropType`.  For example, you could instantiate this template with `MyStruct` like this:

```
PropReader<MyStruct, int, &MyStruct::x> myPropReader;
```

Now, let's see what the rest of the code does.  The body of this class template is reprinted here:

```
void print(Object& o)
{
    PropObject& po = static_cast<PropObject &>(o);
    PropType& t = po.*Prop;

    cout << t << "\n";
}
```

Some of this can be read pretty easily.  The parameter to this function is a reference to an `Object` named `o`, and the last line prints out some field.  These two lines are tricky:

```
PropObject& po = static_cast<PropObject &>(o);
PropType& t = po.*Prop;
```

This first line is a typecast that says "try to cast the argument `o` to a reference of type `PropObject`.  The idea, I'm guessing, is that `Object` is some base class of a lot of different objects.  The parameter to the function is just a plain `Object`, and this cast tries to convert it to something of the appropriate type (recall that `PropObject` is the template argument saying what the type of the object is).  Because this uses `static_cast`, if the conversion isn't defined (for example, you tried to instantiate the template over `int` or `vector<string>`), the code won't compile.  Otherwise, the code trusts that the cast is safe, then gets a reference of type `PropObject` to what the parameter refers to.

Finally, the last line is

```
PropType& t = po.*Prop;
```

This uses the pointer-to-class-member dereference syntax I mentioned earlier to say "select the field pointed at by `Prop` (the template argument), then store a reference to it named `t`.

So, in short, the template

1. Asks you for the type of some object.
2. Asks you for the type of some field in that object.
3. Asks you for a pointer to the field in that object.
4. Provides a `print` function that given an object tries to print out that field.

Whew!  That was tricky!  Hope this helps!

Comment: That was an amazing answer templatetypedef.. no wonder you have that username :)

Answer (score 4):

Declarations in C or C++ are often best read from right to left:

```
PropType PropObject::* Prop
                       ~~~~  The Prop template parameter
                   ~~~       is a pointer to a member
         ~~~~~~~~~~          of a PropObject
~~~~~~~~                     where that member has type PropType
```

This can be seen in action in the instantiations:

```
PropReader<Student, int, &Student::age> r;
```

Here the third template parameter is a pointer to a member of the `Student` class, that has type `int`.

Answer (score 3):

The `PropObject::*` is a pointer-to-member (data member, in this case). It's basically a pointer to a (non-static) member (which are `Student::age` and `Student::grade` in the case of your code).

To use it, you have to specify the `this` object that the function would use. That's done by using either the `.*` or `->*` operator; in this case, the `PropType& t = po.*Prop;` line handles that, where `po` is used as the `this` object for the members.

Answer (score 1):

That's the syntax for passing a pointer to a member as an argument. Specifically in this case it's so that `age` and `grade` members can be passed in. While the template args are specifying the `Student` class it's a member of and that the member properties are `int`.

If you added a string name to student the PropReader declaration might look like this:

```
PropReader<Student, std::string, &Student::name> r3;
```

Answer (score 0):

> But this particular PropType PropObject::* Prop in template
>   declaration bothers me. What does it mean?

```
PropType PropObject::* Prop
```

This defines pointer that pointing a member variable of a class, in this particular case,  the class is PropObject and the variable type is PropType.